# When send data from android to php logcat warning

Tags: java, php, android, httpclient, logcat

When I try to send data from android to php, I get these yellow warnings on logcat:

> Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated

and:

> W/SingleClientConnManager(274): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.

My codes like this:

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", "")); 
    InputStream is=null;
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://zzzzz.com/zzz.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is=entity.getContent();

    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
```

And in my zzz.php I have:

```
<?php

 $email = "aaa";

 if (session_id() == "")
 {
  session_start();
 }
 if (!isset($_SESSION['username']))
 {
   header('Location: ./index.php');
   exit;
 }
 else
 {

 $username = "******";
 $password = "****";
 $host = "****";
 $database = "****";

 $db = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
 if (!$db)
  {
  die('Failed to connect to database server!<br>'.mysql_error());
  }
 else
  {
   mysql_select_db($database, $db) or die('Failed to select database<br>'.mysql_error()); 
   mysql_query("UPDATE Users SET lat='".$email."' WHERE username='{$_SESSION['username']}'");
  }
}
?>
```

By the way, I know mysql_query deprecated, I'll change it.
Anyway above codes does not work. I mean  it doesn't write "aaa" on lat value in mysql. Where is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me as $_SESSION['username'] is not set at any time.

Comment: If I connect with laptop with browser there is not error.It works good.But if I connect with my android phone there are those warnings on logcat.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need both these lines?

```
 httpclient.execute(httppost);
 HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Comment: Sorry I become aware of this; I use Custom web client for my project and it's extend WebChromeClient. So is this line **HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();** still work with custom client ?